# How to use the new OpenType features with TextFormatter?

Tags: wpf, opentype

The `Typography` class can be used to use fancy new font features of OpenType fonts. You use them by decorating `Run`s in xaml like this:

```
<Run Typography.Capitals="SmallCaps">Capitals</Run>
```

That's nice, but I don't want to render directly but convert it to a `Geometry` for further processing.

This is possible regularly with the `FormattedText` class, as in this snippet:

```
var tf = new Typeface(
  new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Pericles"),
  FontStyles.Normal,
  FontWeights.Normal,
  new FontStretch()
);

var brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

var ftext = new FormattedText(
  text,
  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
  FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
  tf,
  72,
  brush
);

var geometry = ftext.BuildGeometry(new Point());
```

I can't find any parameter for things in the Typography class though.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: did you try their documentation?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes.

Comment: can you link to that documentation to show us where you've been looking? (i.e. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745109(v=vs.110).aspx#typography_class, which seems pretty detailed) Also, opentype fonts have been around for a pretty long time now, so I'm not sure which "fancy new features" you mean: it might be helpful to list which actual features you're trying to access (specific GSUB/GPOS features, non-standard opentype tables, etc?)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I mean pretty much the features on the pages you linked. It is detailed, but all examples are for decorating `Run`s - the `FormattedText` class isn't mentioned. You can also quickly determine that the word `Geometry` doesn't appear in it at all, so it probably doesn't say how to create one.

Comment: got a link to the Typogrpahy class, then? Because a simple googling mostly find me http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.Typography, which strongly hints at the fact that this is an experimental class, with a machine-generated bit of docs. So now I'm kind of curious where you read that you could use this class.

Comment: What makes you think I did? It's quite possible that this functionality isn't exposed by WPF at all. Or perhaps it is, but not through the `Typography` class or the `FormattedText` class. That's what my question is about.

Comment: the.. part where you start your post with "The Typography class can be used to use fancy new font features of OpenType fonts"? Either that's true, so you heard/read/discovered that somewhere, or you didn't and then I'm curious how you found this class. Knowing the source of your claim helps us because we can look that source up and use it to do some parallel searching for you.

Comment: I'm no longer sure what the first article was that made me associate the `Typography` class with OpenType font support. It was over a year ago and Silverlight-specific, maybe [this one](http://www.codemag.com/Article/1201031). When you google for "wpf opentype" you get the page you linked as the first hit, and all the examples in it use the `Typography` class to expose OpenType-specific features. So that's why I kind of think `Typography` and OpenType belong together. I'm not fixed on using the class though.

Comment: I posted [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441160/how-to-get-a-scalable-image-representation-from-wpf-controls) - which doesn't deal with OpenType at all - the answer to which would also answer this one.