# How to get a scalable image representation from WPF controls?

Tags: .net, wpf, fonts, typesetting

I'm trying to "render" text outlines in WPF to from a rich text source.

In many cases, the `TextFormatter` class does what I want, as in this snippet:

```
var tf = new Typeface(
  new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Pericles"),
  FontStyles.Normal,
  FontWeights.Normal,
  new FontStretch()
);

var brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

var ftext = new FormattedText(
  text,
  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
  FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
  tf,
  72,
  brush
);

var geometry = ftext.BuildGeometry(new Point());
```

Here, I convert a piece of text to it's outlines (`Geometry`) in a specific typeface and size.

The `FormattedText` class has some limitations though. There is no way to get the paragraph formatting of `FlowDocument`s or OpenType features available from the `Typography` class, for example. There is generally a much more limited control over what it renders when compared to what I could do with a RichTextBox or arbitrary ui elements.

That's why I'm looking for a way to "render" arbitrary ui elements (or at least proper `FlowDocument`s) into outlines the same way I did with normal text in the snippet.

**I'm not looking for a bitmap image - I'm interested in a *scalable representation*, for example something like a `Geometry` instance.**

I suspect it might be possible because I know printing does a conversion of arbitrary xaml to a *scalable* image representation. I just don't want it actually printed.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: what kind of rich text source you have? flow document? rtf? or some other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a way myself:

WPF allows to render in an XpfDocument without needing that document to be printed or stored on disk. It can be a document initialized on a memory stream. It is then "only" a matter of re-opening it and parse the xaml inside.

A bit tricky in the details perhaps, but certainly possible.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this link](http://www.wpfmentor.com/2009/01/how-to-transfer-rich-text-from.html).

Basically, you pass in a `FlowDocument` object and it returns a `FormattedText` object. From there you can invoke `BuildGeometry`.

I'm sure it could be easily modified for whatever your rich text source is.

Comment: Idiot me didn't read the FormattedText doc properly it seems. I obviously even missed the pretty "Lorem ipsum" pic that was obviously rich text. There's the remaining issue of how to get outlines from arbitrary xaml, which is also interesting - but I'll make another bounty for that at a later point. (I need to wait a bit longer before I'm allowed to award the bounty.)